# .bat file execution from a .tex document during compilation

Tags: external-files, auxiliary-files

Is there a way to execute a `.bat` file directly from a latex document when I compile that document?

I would something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
bla bla bla
ecc...
\executebat{C:\...\...\...}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you thinking to launching MakeIndex from inside your LaTeX run?

Comment: You want `\write18`.  For that to work, you will need to compile with `--shell-escape`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, but I know your package "imakeidx" : )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to run LaTeX (`latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`) with the `-shell-escape` option: then this code defines what you need.

```
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\executebat}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@shellescape=\@ne
    \immediate\write18{#1}%
  \else
    \GenericError{}{Shell escape not enabled}{}
      {You have to run (pdf)LaTeX with the option `-shell-escape'}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

However, if your purpose is to run MakeIndex, then the `imakeidx` package does it without user intervention (not with the `article` class unless some precautions are taken).